# Robust statistics, general ideas, set theory

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory, estimation

I am currently reading a paper *Zieliński R.* **Robust statistical procedures: A general approach** and I have a few questions:

1. Function $r_t(P)=\sup\{\rho(Q): Q \in \pi(P)\}-\inf\{\rho(Q): Q \in \pi(P)\}$ is defined as a diameter of a set, so why is there a need to include infimum?
2. How could one justify forumulas for $r_t^+$ and $r_t^-$? I don't really get what's the reason to define it in this way.
3. Why could one say that an estimate $t$ is robust at given point $P$ if $\int t(x)dQ=
   \theta(P)$? How to interpret this integral, as an expected value of a statistic?

A part of an article below:

[image]